# A depends on B, is A dependant, or is B dependant?

Tags: meaning

If A is dependant, what does one call B?

Comment: I used the term in software as Dependantor for B and Depenantee for A. Obviously not a real word, but works for me

Comment: @Mark I would prefer depender and dependee, or, better yet, dependant and principal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A is dependent, it depends on B.  If these were variables, B would be called an independent variable.

Comment: Can I call B the dependency, or dependee?

Comment: Does *A is dependent* also imply *A is dependant*?

Comment: @Ray - the noun form is often spelt with an 'a', so you could say A is a _dependant_, it/he/she is _dependent_ on B.

Comment: @Ray - there's no good word in English for B. *Dependee* follows normal English conventions, but it's not in common use and you'd be better off using another construct rather than a single word to describe it.

Comment: In American English _dependent_ is both adjective, and noun. In British English, _dependant_ is used as noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's true Brits *may* spell the noun "dependant" - but that distinction was never universally honoured, and it's rapidly disappearing altogether. Certainly government & other 'official' bodies normally use *dependent* nowadays.

Answer (score 17):

In programming, if A is a dependant of B, then B is a **dependancy**. This term is also fairly common in project and resource management.

However, in human relationships - if A is a child or spouse that is dependent on B, then A would remain a **dependant** but B would commonly be called a **provider** or maybe a **supporter**.

Comment: 1, I'm pretty sure the IRS counts my kids as _dependants_.

Comment: Perhaps I was not being clear - A (child or spouse) would still be a dependant, but B (the person they depend on) would be a provider.

Comment: +1 (putting back my -1).  I now see your point.

Comment: No worries, even I was confused by my original answer ;)

Comment: This is the more correct answer of the two.

Comment: It should be noted most English speakers who are not familiar with a jargon that gives *dependancy* this special-purpose meaning would assume that it stands for something that is, like A rather than B, dependent on something else.

Answer (score 10):

In project management (and lots of engineering), B is the *prerequisite* for A, in that it must come first. B does not necessarily know or care about A.

Comment: 1 for extending the scope of OP to engineering (and programming).

Comment: For Assignments and Tasks (when establishing a relationship to a Dependency) it makes sense for the other side of that relationship to be referred to as the Prerequisite (from the Dependency's point of view).  Thank you, there are so many posts about this, and your answer is the only one that fits perfectly for me.