# If a person depends upon you, what are you for him?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are you his *dependency*, *dependendee* or something else? What is this type of opposite word called?  I believe it is not called antonym, as that would be *independent*.

Comment: You could say these words are reciprocally related.  For instance, dependent is the reciprocal relation of dependency.

Comment: Related: [A depends on B](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/a-depends-on-b-is-a-dependant-or-is-b-dependant)

Comment: If it's in a bad way: enabler.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say you are his/her **support** or **supporter**.

See [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/support) and scroll down to the "noun" section.

Comment: Neither word really fits.  Support is not used for people, and *supporter* does not imply dependency: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/supporter

Comment: @z7sg: It's been said before that English doesn't really have a single word for the counterpart of a *dependent*. So nothing "really fits", but this certainly gets close.

Answer (score 6):

**provider**

If A depends on B, then B *provides for* A and B is *a provider*.

> to make arrangements for supplying means of support, money, etc.
>   (usually followed by for):  He provided for his children in his will.
>
> to supply means of support (often followed by for):
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/provide

Other words:

- **supporter**  If A depends on B, then B *supports* A and B is *a supporter*.
- **supplier**  If A depends on B, then B *supplies* A and B is *a supplier*.
- **caregiver**  If A depends on B, then B *cares for* A and B is *a caregiver*.

Comment: Best answer for the type of dependant I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If someone depends on you and you have a legal obligation to protect, support or care for them and their interests, then you are their *[legal guardian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_guardian)*.  The person who depends on you is your *ward* or *dependant*.

An informal word for the person who you depend on is *your [rock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rock)*.

**1611**, *King James Bible*, *Matthew 16:18*

> And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it.

**1991**, Robert Harling and Andrew Bergman, *Soapdish*, Paramount Pictures

> Celeste Talbert: She is my rock, my right hand.

Comment: But that's only in one particular sense of "dependant". The OP did not restrict the question to this meaning of "dependant". I can't think of a word that would cover this for all meanings of "dependant".

Comment: So far as I know, there is no single word derived from *depend* for OP's sense, so this is the best answer. I'm gobsmacked that several people have upvoted what to me is a manifestly incorrect answer.

Comment: @Colin I have added a less formal alternative.

Comment: I find *rock* too metaphoric. It's fine for figurative speech or literary use, but would sound odd if used in plain everyday talk.

Comment: @Cesar No that's not correct, it's fine for everyday use.  Spoken examples from COCA: "I call her my rock, you know. She anchors me. She is the woman that raised me, she's the woman that made me who I am."  ~ Alicia Keys "He is just so loving, so caring. He was my rock." ~ Unidentified female 48 Hours CBS

Comment: @z7sg: I see that as a nice metaphor: "I call her my rock, she anchors me". The lyricism is clear; you may speak like that regularly, but it's still metaphorical.

Answer (score 2):

Simple language ordinarily trumps oral frippery (cf. Hemingway's "poor Faulkner" comeback), as exemplified by the first part of this sentence, but... There, are, times. So, thusly..

#### *[Maecenas](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maecenas)*

> /miːˈsiːnæs/
>
> A generous patron, esp. of art or literature.

#### *[benefactor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benefactor)*

> A person who supports or helps a person, institution, etc., esp by giving money; patron.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the most general alternative, but **sponsor** is sometimes used.

The Medicis were Galileo's sponsors.

If the support is monetary and public, **patron** can also be used.

The Medicis were Galileo's patrons.
The NEA was Billingham's patron.

If the support is 'active', then **advocate** can be appropriate.

The indigent depended upon his advocate to navigate the bureaucracy.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic direct straight counterpart to "dependent," there was nothing. But in computer science and technical land, your "dependent" has a "dependency" on you, the "dependee."

So, for the most generic (abstract) direct counterpart to "dependent," it could be "dependee" if you were brave enough to help propagate it to more general use over time.

A not-great source is here, 
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee, but I feel like it does not do the (newish) word justice.

Comment: This would be improved with a reference to your source.