# Whats the opposite of the dependent

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm creating an application/website, that you can control "assets" with. (The fact this is an app/website is irrelevant, I'm just giving some detail)

Inside these *assets*, you can define *attributes*, and you optionally set the attribute(s) to be *dependent* on another assets attributes, I call these "dependent attributes", as that term refers to the relationship going from the child to the parent

Now if you're viewing the the parent asset, what would I call the relationship going the opposite direction? I keep thinking "dependents", but that would be confusing as heck.

If "dependent" isn't the best verbiage for something that needs to be described going both directions, then whats another good word? I actually looked up 'dependent' on thesaurus.com, and didn't find anything I thought would suffice

Comment: Welcome!  unfortunately, naming things (especially programming things) is explicitly off-topic in per our [help].  Take the [tour] if you'd like to get a better feel for the site.  (Would "dependencies" work?)

Comment: Umm... **Independent** usually is the opposite of dependent.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It looks like your question nearly fits the tag `single-word-requests`. You can add the tag to your question, along with a sample sentence such as "The child is the *dependent* of the parent, so the parent is the ___ of the child." This makes your question more specific and helps the community to be more helpful to you.

Comment: From http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site:     Naming, including naming programming variables/classes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because qs on " Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" are out of scope for this site.

Comment: @Justin as developers we usually follow the pattern used in css selectors and elsewhere:  ancestor(s) > parent(s) > child(ren) > descendant(s) where parent and child are a one degree apart and ancestors and descendants are more than one degree apart.  Children of the same parent are usually called siblings.  AFAIK naming conventions and clean coding are on topic for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com and stack overflow. And there are probably sound answers there already.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, `Parent` and `Child` pair well together, as do `Controlling` and `Dependent`.

- If A is `dependent` on B, then B `controls` A.
- If X is a `parent` of Y, then Y is a `child` of X.

Answer (score 1):

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019554/naming-the-things-something-else-depends-on) on Stack Overflow has some software specific terms you might look into. And [this Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36033/if-a-person-depends-upon-you-what-are-you-for-him) from this SE shows more literature related possibilities.

Some of the listings I found at these links that are related:

> Parent Property
>
> Master Property
>
> Control Property
>
> [Advocate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/advocate?s=t)
>
> [Sponsor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sponsor)
>
> [Supporter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supporter?s=t)