# Opposite of "depends on"

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a web page (A) which contains some repackaged content from another website (B).

A depends on B.

If B were to keep a list of web pages, like A, that depend on it, what could we call that list?

I came up with `dependants`, but I'm finding people confusing it with `dependencies` (i.e. the opposite relationship).

I also came up with `referents`, but I'm worried that it may be just as confusing. Is there a better word?

By the way, I rejected the word `children` as I think it is also confusing in this situation.

Comment: By "A depends on X", do you mean "A requires X in order to exist/happen"? If so you could call X a "prerequisite" of A.

Comment: There are a large number of similar questions in the "Related" sidebar. To determine whether or not any are duplicates needs more detail in this question. What is the context?

Comment: Check [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/a-depends-on-b-is-a-dependant-or-is-b-dependant) in particular.

Comment: I've updated the question to make the scenario clearer.

Comment: *Downstream* packages depend on things further *upstream*.

Comment: Isn't the opposite of "Depends on" "bare-assed"?

Comment: You could use "partner sites".

Comment: In the Linux package management world they call them "*reverse-dependencies*" .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd borrow a term from the domain of copyright and patent law, and refer to those sites which reuse content from another site as "*derivative* sites."

Their repackaged content is *derived* from the "parent" site's content; their content is *derivative*.

One could use the adjectival noun "the *derivates*" or "the *derivatives*" to refer to those sites that depend on the other site.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon vs Contingent to

```
    ---> X --->
```

Like:
Needs this to happen before... VERSUS. This is before something else happens